# Compare user input against os.getcwd(), then continue or quit with a message

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to display the actual CWD, and also **have the user manually enter** it for confirmation. If they are the same, then continue the program, if they are not the same, then exit the program with a message.

I am getting errors with the `else:`.

```
import os
import sys

print('Current working directory (CWD) is:', os.getcwd())
confcwd = input('Confirm intended CWD by enerting: ')
if confcwd == os.getcwd():
    print ("CWD confirmed.")
    else:
    print ("ERROR! Unable to verify CWD.")
    exit()
```

(This one safeguard that file manipulation do not take place in the wrong dir.)

Answer (score 1):

Indentation matters in Python:

```
import os
import sys

print('Current working directory (CWD) is:', os.getcwd())
confcwd = input('Confirm intended CWD by enerting: ')
if confcwd == os.getcwd():
    print ("CWD confirmed.")
else:
    print ("ERROR! Unable to verify CWD.")
    exit()
```

Comment: Thank you, I am learning! A bonus Q: how can I make the user entered path case insensitive, i.e., `C:\a\b\` == `c:\a\b`?